# Is a convex and lower semicontinuous function defined on a closed and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty convex and closed set, and let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a lower semicontinuous and convex function.

Does this imply that $f$ is continuous on $A$?

I know that in the (relative) interior of $A$, $f$ is locally lipchitz so my question is about the points on the boundary.  Of course, I consider the continuity of $f$ with respect to $A$ and not the continuity of the extended function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\left\{+\infty\right\}$ defined by $\tilde{f}(x):=f(x)$ for $x\in A$ and $\tilde f(x):=+\infty$ for $x\notin A$, which is obviously not upper semicontinuous on the boundary of $A$.

If the answer to my question is negative a counterexample would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the examples from [Extension of bounded convex function to boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451632/extension-of-bounded-convex-function-to-boundary) by redefining them on the boundary to achieve lower semicontinuity.

For example, you can do the following. We consider the set
$$A:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 \le y \}$$
and the function
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}y \qquad\forall (x,y) \in A \setminus \{(0,0)\}$$
and $f(0,0) = 0$. If I did not miss something, this should satisfy your assumptions while being discontinuous in $(0,0)$.

Comment: One question: if we take square from this function, we come up to function which is homogeneous  of degree 2 while keep all other properties . Am I right?

Comment: @Redshoes: Yes, I think so.

Comment: This is a very nice example. I've been trying to construct a discontinuous, lower semicontinuous convex function for a few days, probably a week. I was trying to produce one where the discontinuity would "come from the boundary" rather than from the inside. Do you know if the function defined by $e^{ix}\mapsto x$ for $x\in[0,2\pi)$ has a convex extension to the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Yes, I think so. You can just take the largest convex function which lies below your function on the boundary. Its graph is the union of the segments from $(1,0,0)$ to $(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi),\phi)$ for $\phi \in (0,2\pi)$.